# How to autoselect the letter when cursor is at its position?

Tags: qt, qt4

Hi guys I am using double spin box in qt,in it i am having 0.00,what I want to do it is,when my cursor is at 1st zero,it should be selected,instead I press shift key to select,when I press right arrow key,then 2nd 0 should be selected and so on.How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should subclass `QDoubleSpinBox` and then `lineEdit()->setInputMask("9.99")` will do the thing. Sample code:

```
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QLineEdit>

class MyDoubleSpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyDoubleSpinBox(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDoubleSpinBox(parent) {
        lineEdit()->setInputMask("9.99");
    }
};
```

Comment: @Amar I just updated my answer with a small fix and a sample code.

Comment: I am a newbie at Qt,I dont know how to use the code u suggested.Can you please tell me how to use it?